# Where is sphinx-build installed in Mac OS-X?

Tags: python, macos, python-sphinx

I have the latest `sphinx-build` installed, but it's of the form

```
sphinx-build-2.7
```

Each of the document `Makefile` asks for `sphinx-build` in the command specifics. Although I could edit the `SHINXBUILD` variable in it, I would like to have a separate `sphinx-build` command that would point to the original `sphinx-build-2.7` command using `ln`.

Alas, I don't know where is it installed. I tried

```
whereis sphinx-build-2.7
```

But it just returned with a blank output.

So, how could I find out where is `sphinx-build` installed?

Specs: Python-2.7.9, Mac-OS-X 10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type sphinx-build` in the Terminal will you give you the location.